# EWMA Covariance Matrix in Pandas - Optimization

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, covariance

I would like to calculate the EWMA Covariance Matrix from a DataFrame of stock price returns using Pandas and have followed the methodology in [PyPortfolioOpt](https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyPortfolioOpt).

I like the flexibility of using Pandas objects and functions but when the set of assets grows the function is becomes very slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ewma_cov_pairwise_pd(x, y, alpha=0.06):
    x = x.mask(y.isnull(), np.nan)
    y = y.mask(x.isnull(), np.nan)
    covariation = ((x - x.mean()) * (y - y.mean()).dropna()
    return covariation.ewm(alpha=0.06).mean().iloc[-1]

def ewma_cov_pd(rets, alpha=0.06):
    assets = rets.columns
    n = len(assets)
    cov = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            cov[i, j] = cov[j, i] = ewma_cov_pairwise_pd(
                rets.iloc[:, i], rets.iloc[:, j], alpha=alpha)
    return pd.DataFrame(cov, columns=assets, index=assets)
```

I would like to improve the speed of the code ideally while still using Pandas but the bottleneck is within the DataFrame.ewm() function which uses 90% of the calculation time.

**If using this function was a binding constraint, what is the most efficient way of improving the speed at which the code runs?**  I was considering taking a brute force approach and using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor but perhaps there is a better solutions.

```
n = 100  # n is typically 2000
rets = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1., size=(n, n)))
cov_pd = ewma_cov_pd(rets)
```

The true time-series data can contain leading nulls and potentially missing values after that although the latter less likely.

**Update I**

A potential solution which leverages off the answer provided by Quang Hoang and produces the expected results in a far more reasonable time would be something similar to:

```
def ewma_cov_frame_qh(rets, alpha=0.06):
    weights = (1-alpha) ** np.arange(len(df))[::-1]
    normalized = (rets-rets.mean()).to_numpy()    
    out = (weights * normalized.T) @ normalized / weights.sum()
    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=rets.columns, columns=rets.columns)


def ewma_cov_qh(rets, alpha=0.06):
    syms = rets.columns
    covar = pd.DataFrame(index=rets.columns, columns=rets.columns)
    delta = rets.isnull().sum(axis=1).shift(1) - rets.isnull().sum(axis=1)
    dates = delta.loc[delta != 0].index.tolist()
     
    for date in dates:
        frame = rets.loc[rets.index >= date].dropna(axis=1, how='any')
        cov = ewma_cov_frame_qh(frame).reindex(index=syms, columns=syms)
        covar = covar.fillna(cov)
   
    return covar

cov_qh = ewma_cov_qh(rets)
```

This violates the requirement that the underlying covariance is calculated using the native Pandas/Numpy functions and calculation time will depend on the number leading na's in the data set.

**Update II**

A potential improvement on the above which uses (a naive implementation of) multiprocessing and improves the calculation time by a further 42.5% on my machine is listed below:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from functools import partial
    
def ewma_cov_mp_worker(date, rets, alpha=0.06):
    syms = rets.columns
    frame = rets.loc[rets.index >= date].dropna(axis=1, how='any')
    return ewma_cov_frame_qh(frame, alpha=alpha).reindex(index=syms, columns=syms)


def ewma_cov_mp(rets, alpha=0.06):
    covar = pd.DataFrame(index=rets.columns, columns=rets.columns)
    delta = rets.isnull().sum(axis=1).shift(1) - rets.isnull().sum(axis=1)
    dates = delta.loc[delta != 0].index.tolist()

    func = partial(ewma_cov_mp_worker, rets=rets, alpha=alpha)
    covs = {}

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as exec:
        future_to_date = {exec.submit(func, date): date for date in dates}
        covs = {future_to_date[future]: future.result() for future in as_completed(future_to_date)}

    for date in dates:
        covar.fillna(covs[date], inplace=True)

    return covar
```

[I have not added as answer as not addressed the original question and I am optimistic there is a better solution.]

Answer (score 3):

since you don't really care for `ewm`, i.e, you only take the last value. We can try matrix multiplication:

```
def ewma(df, alpha=0.94):
    weights = (1-alpha) ** np.arange(len(df))[::-1]

    # fillna with 0 here
    normalized = (df-df.mean()).fillna(0).to_numpy()
    
    out =  ((weights * normalized.T) @ normalized / weights.sum()
    
    return out

 # verify
 out = ewma(df)
 print(out[0,1] == ewma_cov_pairwise(df[0],df[1]) )
 # True
```

And this took about `150 ms` on my system with `df.shape==(2000,2000)` while your code refuses to run within minutes :-).

Comment: Thanks Quang and like what you have proposed.  Issue is the data can contain leading missing values (something I did not mention in the above).  So in your example if df.iloc[0, 0] = np.nan then will not work.   Guess I could iterate through recursively. Also if I replace alpha with **kwargs can leverage off any other params in native pandas function.

Comment: @user2579685 fill nan with 0 wouldn’t work? I’m not sure what changes when you have leading nan. What would you expect when that happens?

Comment: I would want to calculate the pairwise covar over the common observations across both x and y.

Comment: @user2579685 updated, I tested setting `df.loc[:5,0] = np.nan` with `fillna` as shown in the answer. The two approaches returns the same answer.

Comment: But without filling the na's with zeros the pandas function gets the result I want and if I break your function down to operate on pairwise basis improvement far more moderate as you would expect.

Comment: code is missing a right parentheses:

out =  ((weights * normalized.T) @ normalized / weights.sum()