# Pandas exponentially weighted covariance implementation for online version

Tags: python, pandas, covariance

Pandas has a function compute rolling covariance over time. e.g. if I have df

```
          Column2   Column2
                         
2017-10-23       NaN       NaN
2017-10-24 -0.147631  0.161791
2017-10-25  0.044194 -0.466305
2017-10-26 -0.069876  0.127095
2017-10-27  0.142261  0.807302
2017-10-30 -0.178176 -0.319247
2017-10-31  0.108544  0.094446
```

then to get the exponentially weighted covariance

```
df.ewm(span=5).cov()
```

Does anyone know the actual implementation of the underlying exponentially weighted covariance? I'm trying to code up my own online version (e.g. cache the state and just use the most recent data to update the covariance matrix)

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926851/ewma-covariance-matrix-in-pandas-optimization/63927773#63927773).

Comment: Thanks - are you aware of any online algo to compute the ewm covariance? I know you can track all of the individual elementwise covariances but would like to avoid that if possible